# Change zoom on map update (JS)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have function for map updating

Here is  code

```
function update() {

            ajaxLoader.removeClass('mc-warning-noConnection');
            ajaxLoader.show();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Mobile/Map/GetMapData',
                type: 'GET',
                timeout: 10000,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.redirectUrl) window.location.replace(data.redirectUrl);
                    else if (data.error) alert(data.error);
                    else {
                        setTimeout(function () { ajaxLoader.hide() }, 300);
                        data.forEach(function (vehicleData) {
                            mapWrapper.getEntity(vehicleData.Imei).update(vehicleData);
                        });
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    ajaxLoader.addClass('mc-warning-noConnection');
                },
                complete: function () {
                    timeout = setTimeout(update, 10000);
                }
            });
        }
```

It need to get values from db via controller

Here is controller code.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> GetMapData()
    {
        var mapData = await repository.GetVehicleMapData(15, null).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Session["PreviousMapQueryTime"] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5); //5 minutes offset because tables aren't always up-to-date

        return CreateJsonDataResult(mapData);
    }
```

And than pass them to map and update markers.

Here is MapWrapper script

[MapWrapper](https://pastebin.com/ZpbidSxr)

With markers all okay, but zoom when updating not works.

When I reload map all okay. But not from updating without reloading whole page.

Where is problem and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `mapWrapper.zoomToLayer(layerID)` function after update entities, where Layerid is ID of layer where your entities placed.

```
success: function (data) {
                    if (data.redirectUrl) window.location.replace(data.redirectUrl);
                    else if (data.error) alert(data.error);
                    else {
                        setTimeout(function () { ajaxLoader.hide() }, 300);
                        data.forEach(function (vehicleData) {
                            mapWrapper.getEntity(vehicleData.Imei).update(vehicleData);
                        });
                          mapWrapper.zoomToLayer(layerID);
                    }
                },
```

Comment: Yes, I found that my problem in zoom. Thanks